# Luis or text analytics for conversational data extraction

Tags: azure, machine-learning, nlp, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I'm currently working on a bot that helps a user fill in a form in a conversational way. I'm wondering if I should pick LUIS or azure text analytics for this. Or maybe both? Since I'll need to respond to certain intents but answering a question obviously has no intent. Or can I count answering a question as an intent. Either way I'll have to deal with various types of answers ranging from well ranges to names, dates and sentiments. And to add to this: it'll need to support dutch.

**Simple example:**

*Bot asks:*

> On a scale of 1 - 10 how do you feel about *some subject*?

*User responds:*

> Well I would give it a 10

*Bot extracts:*

```
feelingScore = 10
```

**More complex example**

*Bot asks:*

> How do you feel about *some subject*?

*User responds:*

> Well I would give it a 10

*Bot extracts:*

```
feeling = "10"
```

*User responds:*

> I honestly didn't feel that good about it.

*Bot extracts:*

```
feeling = "not that good" (or possibly a sentiment score)
```

Comment: can you provide samples of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I just added some examples. I can get you some more examples tomorrow if these aren't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no action based on user's input, I don't see a reason for using LUIS. You can achieve what you want using Text Analytics.

PS: Please notice that even tough users reply with a 10, the sentiment analysis may not be 100%.

Example:

- "I will give it a 10" -> sentiment score is 95
- "Well I would give it a 10" -> sentiment score is 85

But at the same time, you can check the NAMED ENTITIES and get the extracted number from it (when provided in the answer)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/

Comment: Thanks! Then I guess I'll use both. LUIS for stuff like canceling or rescheduling the questionnaire and the rest will just be text analytics. Just need to figure out a way to separate them somehow. (First time using these tools)